# Can I change the provider to use aws / aws-sdk-php?

Tags: php, api, sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am searching a library PHP to use the **S3 protocol** only (not AWS S3 by Amazon).

And I found the AWS SDK for PHP : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php .

But, can I change the provider to use it ?

For example : Can I manage S3 servers of Scaleway ? Ceph ? And so on ?

Thank you :)

Zak,

Comment: Not clear enough of the question. Are you trying to work with s3 API through AWS sdk on PHP?

Comment: Could you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to work with the S3 protocol no matter the provider (AWS, Scaleway, Minio, and do on.). My question is : Can I use the aws-sdk-php to manage my objects (push, update, delete, create, and so on) ?

For example : Can I manage my objects with this sdk on the S3 from Scaleway provider ( https://www.scaleway.com/en/object-storage/ ) ?

Don't hesitate to tell me if I am not clear again ^^

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if still relevant for you, but I did manage to use the AWS SDK for PHP with Scaleway Object Storage.

The only trick is to set `bucket-endpoint` to `true`, provide the `endpoint` as the bucket endpoint from your bucket settings in Scaleway, and one more crucial thing, provide the credentials as array, instead of letting the SDK generate / check them. See code sample below:

```
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'bucketregion', //eg. 'fr-par'
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'your access key',
        'secret' => 'your secret key',
    ],
    'endpoint' => 'http://mybucket.s3.fr-par.scw.cloud',
    'bucket_endpoint' => true
]);

try {
    $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'=>'butcketname',
        'Key' =>  'path-where-you-want-to-upload-in-bucket',
        'SourceFile' => 'system-path-to-file',
        'ACL'    => 'public-read', //for public access
    ));
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    //code when fails
}
```

I just used this code as I had the same issue and I can 100% confirm this code works to upload files to Scaleway object storage by using AWS PHP SDK, as of April 2022.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works for me although I had an issue : somehow the bucket name is removed from the URL when requested so that I got a 403 with a URL like https://s3.fr-par.scw.cloud//path/to/my/file (notice the double /). To work around this I had to force the bucket name directly in the object's key ('Key' => $bucket . '/path/to/my/file').